# Regex numbers and units

Tags: regex, clojure

I am new to regex, but have the idea in mind to extract numbers and units from an input string. My initial idea is to construct an array of possible units of interest. Then look through the input for a sequence of digits followed by the units. However, I am unsure how to couple the idea of the array and digits within regex.

Most likely I plan to construct the array using `core.matrix` array function. Although I am not sure if this is the best approach for the regex coupling of digits and units.

An example input might be "here we are looking for 100kg bags of rice."

Or, possibly "here we found a 100 kg bag of rice."

Whereby there might exist white space in between the digits and units.

Comment: Sorry, You really need to be more specific on what exactly you intend to extract (with examples!)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Using `re-seq` and the right regex should get you started:

```
(defn find-things [s]
  (map (fn [[_ count unit]] {:count count, :unit unit})
       (re-seq #"(\d+)\s*(kg|lb)" s)))

(find-things "here we are looking for 100kg bags of rice.")
; => ({:count "100", :unit "kg"})

(find-things "here we found a 100 lb bag of rice.")
; => ({:count "100", :unit "lb"})

(find-things "mix 99lb quinoa with 45kg barley.")
; => ({:count "99", :unit "lb"}
;     {:count "45", :unit "kg"})
```

**Edit**

Upon rereading your question, I see that you'd like to have a dynamic set of units. Here's an example for that:

```
(def units ["lb" "kg" "L" "ml"])
(def unit-match (clojure.string/join "|" units))
(def matching-str (str "(\\d+)\\s*(" unit-match ")")) ;; note escaped backslashes
(def matching-pattern (re-pattern  matching-str))

; replace the literal regexp in the function above with `matching-pattern`

(find-things "add 100ml to 900ml to yield 1 L!")
; => ({:count "100", :unit "ml"}
;     {:count "900", :unit "ml"}
;     {:count "1", :unit "L"})
```

Answer (score 1):

The regex `[0-9]+ ?[a-zA-Z]+` will find the numbers, and then you can split the result with the regex `(?<=[0-9]) ?(?=[a-zA-Z])`.